# Crystal Report Page Footer (Increase Page footer size )

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I currently have a “report” which is actually a document that I print for my web application.
I need to print a front page with details, and a back page with a terms and conditions.

The document might have 1 to X pages.
Each page must have a terms and conditions on the back. Meaning, even pages will have a terms and conditions.

i want this kind of view

Page 1:
header
details (showing 3 registers)
Footer

Page 2: Insert a Terms and Conditions Page

Page 3:
Header
Detailes (showing 3 registers)
Footer

Page 4: Terms and Conditions

Page 5:
Header
Detailes (4 registers)
Footer

Page 6: Terms and Conditions

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of number of lines T&C will extend then place the field and then manually increase the size, else check the option `Can Grow` which will take care of automatically increasing the size of the field.

To print T&C on even page, go to supress and then write below condition

```
pagenumber/2<>0
```